# Visual Studio Code Java JUnit Not Outputting to Console

Tags: java, junit, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code with the `java.home` setting set to the directory of my JDK 11 installation. I have a Maven project and use 3.5.4 and have it added to my path, so I can run `mvn` in a console. Maven works as expected, as well as running the code's main method, however when I run a JUnit 4.12 test by clicking `Run Test` that is shown over an annotated `@Test` method, the test runs, however I am unable to view any console output from the JUnit tests.

Under `Output`, I have the `Test Output` window, which is where I would expect the console to output, however nothing shows up even though the test method runs `System.out.println("test");`

How would I go about making JUnit 4.12 display the test console output when a test is run by clicking the `Run Test` button shown over a test method?

Comment: I know this is old, but for people who land here, what version of VS Code?

Comment: @chrisinmtown From my research, I believe this was VSCode 1.29, although there are reports of the issue on 1.27 and 1.28 as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently a [known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-java-test/issues/344) in the plugin. The workaround is to disable the Maven plugin. (You can still use the terminal within VS Code to run Maven)

Comment: Is this issue still present?

Comment: @zygimantus If I remember correctly, the issue was no longer present a few months after this. I haven't used it in over a year now though, so it may have come back.